# Can Zapier set the Salesforce Owner ID as a Queue?

Tags: zapier, salesforce

Importing leads into Salesforce via Zapier.

[image]

Owner ID in Zapier won't display the Queue names and you can't enter arbitrary values.

Is it possible to set the Lead Owner ID to a Queue using Zapier?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to "Use a custom Value (Advanced)" and provide your Queue id, starting with 00G I think.